# Elasticsearch stores Date as Array

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In my project I am using Elasticsearch 6.x to store data.

When I store a Date it is saved as an Array.

The conversion form LocalDate to Array is within the java object "ObjectMapper" and the method "writeValueAsString"

this is my Mapping:

```
"myDate": {
  "type": "date",
  "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
}
```

this is the result:

```
"myDate": [
2017
,
11
,
10
]
```

I convert the LocalDate in input in millisecond and when I search for date range I have no hits

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that issue is related to ObjectMapper and not Elastic, you can try to configure ObjectMapper like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule

...

ObjectMapper().registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this solution is not applicable. I pass an Object with multiple fields, I cannot set the object mapper only for JavaTimeModule. Moreover that part of the project was not developed by me and this what is used:

ObjectMapperUtil.newObjectMapper.registerModule(new Json4sScalaModule);

Comment: @MassimoB can you share more details in your question then? Smth like  [mcve]. It's hard to guess

Comment: In the end I have added this to the mapper: objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS); and now I have "myDate": "2017-11-10"